# Open postman passing the information to be executed

Tags: javascript, json, api, http, postman

Does Postman allow it to be opened by an external program?

I am not able to find information.

What I want to do is this:

- The user accesses the site
- This queries the server
- Taking information via http, a kind of json or other
- To then pass it to Postman if user has installed, in order to configure the call to be executed.

Json:

```
{
type: "GET",
url: "https://...",
headers: {},
body:{},
...
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the usecase, it just seems a little but strange to me. Not sure I really follow what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @DannyDainton: I'm writing the documentation for bees, I'm using this https://redocly.github.io/redoc/#tag/pet, as you can see there is a part on the right where it shows you the type of call Get, Post, address, payload, etc.
I would like to do so via a button if you click to send all this information to postman to be able to set the call and then be able to be executed by the user if he wants.
I don't know if I explained myself.